# Коммиты для Unity3d-проектов

Tags: git, unity3d, контроль-версий

Когда просто писал на VS C++, например, то коммитил только исходники и этого было достаточно.

**Что нужно коммитить для Unity-проектов?**

Одних исходников явно не достаточно, так как на сцене тоже есть разные объекты. Всю папку с проектом тоже не вариант, так как, во-первых, много весит, во-вторых, например, папка Temp не хочет коммитится пока редактор запущен, да и логика подсказывает что есть куча файлов, которые заново создадутся если их удалить!

И как в Git выбирать какие файлы коммитить? (По одному каждый раз вносить долго!)

Comment: С тем "как" вносить помогли (Спасибо demol0cv), осталось узнать "что" нужно вносить в коммит)

Comment: Не могу ответить сам на свой вопрос, но на http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/369755/unity-on-github.html посоветовали занести в .gitignore вот такой список. 

*.sln
*.userprefs
*.csproj
*.pidb
*.unityproj
.DS_Store
/Library/FailedAssetImports.txt
/Library/cache/
/Library/previews/
/Library/ScriptAssemblies
/obj
/Temp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используешь .gitignore то нужно добавить его к коммиту, сделать коммит (в .gitignore уже должны быть записи об игногрируемых файлах), затем удалить из проекта ненужные файлы, сделать "git add ." и сделать коммит подтвердив удаление файлов, после этого должно всё работать и должны игнорироваться файлы по маскам из ".gitignore". Если я правильно помню то .gitignore поддерживает регулярки, но 100% гарантировать не могу. Далее если хочешь добавить новые файлы в игнор то изменяешь .gitignore и делаешь коммит как будто сорцы поправил.

Comment: Да, забыл сказать, .gitignore должен быть в каталоге который является корневым для каталога .git, ну скорее всего этот каталог будет и корневым для всего проекта

Comment: demol0cv, пример содержимого файла .gitignore привести можешь?

Comment: Для примера, дельфя 7 создаёт временные файлы с расширением .~pas, а также компилит проект в папку с сорцами, что-бы проигнорить их просто в .gitignore пишем:

<code>*.~pas
*.~dcu
*.exe</code>

после этого добавляем его в репу, делаем коммит, затем удаляем все ненужные файлы и снова делаем коммит - всё! В следующий раз наши временные файлы создаваемые IDE не будут включаться в коммит даже если сделать "git add ." :)

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось)

Comment: на `gitignore io` неплохой генератор игнор-файлов. [пример хорошего gitignore](https://www.gitignore.io/api/unity,csharp,visualstudio)

Answer (score 3):

Лучше всего начинать с документации)
Здесь как настроить внешнюю систему контроля версий
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html
Здесь как  использовать Smartmerge для того чтобы мержить сцены и префабы
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html

Ну а вот так выглядит файл .gitignore. Его надо обновить для своей папки с проектом.

```
# =============== #
# Unity generated #
# =============== #
Temp/
Library/
# ===================================== #
# Visual Studio / MonoDevelop generated #
# ===================================== #
ExportedObj/
obj/
*.svd
*.userprefs
/*.csproj
*.pidb
*.suo
/*.sln
*.user
*.unityproj
*.booproj
# ============ #
# OS generated #
# ============ #
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

При использовании отдельных плагинов не трудно его расширить. Я когда использую Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Unity добавляю еще в список файлы из каталога с UnityVS.

Comment: Охохо) Спасибо конечно, но я уже даже забыл когда последний раз Unity была установлена у меня)

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю на сколько это поможет но меня спас `.gitignore` когда нужно было игнорить исполняемые файлы и временный файлы `IDE` при `git add` . А вот с самим `Unity` я не знаком к сожалению.

[gitignore(5) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрел! Но не разобрался!

В .git/info/exclude я дописываю, например, *.txt 
Но 123.txt все равно не игнорируется(

что то я делаю не так!
Можете примерчик написать?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы уменьшить размер проекта заливаемого на сервер и исключить загрузку временных файлов, настроек AssetStore и прочего я использую файл .gitignore следующего вида:

```
Library/
Temp/
Obj/
Build/
Builds/
Assets/AssetStore*

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedOBj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityprof
*.sin
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.meta

# Unity3D Generated File On Crash Reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage
```

[Источник](https://youtu.be/f5tUSQ0apxg)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте файл .gitignore при помощи GitExtensions или Visual Studio.
Добавьте в него строчку Temp/.